# Accessing the parent of a root widget - kivy

Tags: kivy

I have a lot of code that doesn't matter for this question, so I will just explain how my widget tree is constructed.

I have two screens and different layouts, buttons and widgets on them. Basically like this:

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen1: 
    Screen2: 
        FloatLayout:
            Button1
            Button2
            Button3
            Widget1
            Widget2:
                Label: 
                    text:
                    pos: root.width*0.8, root.height*0.8
```

I want to position Label inside of a Widget because I will be adding more Labels to it, but don't know how to access the Screen2 width. If I use root.width, I get the width of the parent widget which is smaller than window, and can't use ratios with it. I tried accessing the window.width but it gives me an error with ids.

I would appreciate if someone would explain me how to access different parents through ids. Thank you!

Comment: I think you should do it this way :  `root.parent.parent.parent.....width`   use parent until you reach at desired widget.

Comment: use an id for Screen2

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question:

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen1: 
    Screen2:
        id: screen2 
        FloatLayout:
            Button1
            Button2
            Button3
            Widget1
            Widget2:
                Label: 
                    text:
                    pos: screen2.width*0.8, screen2.height*0.8
```

However, it would probably be better to use layout classes to avoid having to manually specify this stuff.